# Wrap class around 2 repeating classes in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="imageRowHeader">
 Header Content
</div>
<div class="imageRowContent">
  <img src="image.jpg">
</div>

<div class="imageRowHeader">
 Header Content 2
</div>
<div class="imageRowContent">
  <img src="image2.jpg">
</div>
```

Repeating numerous times.

I want to use jQuery to make it look like this (I can't alter the HTML directly).

```
<div class="imageRow">
    <div class="imageRowHeader">
     Header Content
    </div>
    <div class="imageRowContent">
      <img src="image.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="imageRow">
    <div class="imageRowHeader">
     Header Content
    </div>
    <div class="imageRowContent">
      <img src="image.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over each `imageRowHeader`, then for the current header and next content sibling element, call [wrapAll()](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

```js
$('.imageRowHeader').each(function() {
  $(this).next().addBack().wrapAll('<div class="imageRow"></div>')
})
```

```css
.imageRow {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageRowHeader">
  Header Content
</div>
<div class="imageRowContent">
  <img src="image.jpg">
</div>

<div class="imageRowHeader">
  Header Content 2
</div>
<div class="imageRowContent">
  <img src="image2.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!